# jQuery DatePicker - Does not disappear in IE7 after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the standard jQuery datepicker which works fine for me in all browsers except Internet Explorer 7 - the date can be selected, and the text field does populate, but the datepicker itself doesn't disappear.

I didn't modify the script at all so I don't really have any unique code to post - I was really just wondering if anyone has experienced this before or knows of any workarounds?

Thanks in advance!

Al